# quantization of a semi-infinite waveguide coupled capacitively to a finite waveguide segment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

I want to treat a semi-infinite co-planar wave-guide coupled capacitively to a cpw resonator. I set the linear capacitance, linear inductance, $\bar{h}$ to be $1$ in the following notations.

---

I know how to write the Lagrangian of an isolated wave-guide segment, with open ends ($I=0$), and then decompose the wave on it in terms of many standing wave modes

$I=0\implies \partial_x\varphi(0)=\partial_x\varphi(L)=0$

$L=\int_0^L \frac{1}{2}(\dot\varphi)^2-\frac{1}{2}(\partial_x\varphi)^2 dx$

$\varphi(x)=\sum_j \varphi_j\cos(\frac{2j\pi x}{2L})$

then with some factors here and there, doing the Legendre transformation
$H=...=\sum_j j (q_j^2+j^2\varphi_j^2)=\sum_j j \omega_1 (a^\dagger a+0.5)$

---

Now I want to canonically quantize the system, starting from the following Lagrangian:

$L=L_1+L_2+L_c$

$L_1=\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{1}{2}(\dot\varphi_1)^2-\frac{1}{2}(\partial_x\varphi_1)^2 dx$

$L_2=\int_0^L \frac{1}{2}(\dot\varphi_2)^2-\frac{1}{2}(\partial_x\varphi_2)^2 dx$

$L_c=\frac{C}{2}(\dot\varphi_1(0)-\dot\varphi_1(0))^2$

The problem that I encounter is that I don't know how exactly which modes to choose for both systems, since the boundary condition $I=0$ on $x=0$ end no longer hold.

I would like to get a form of $H=H_b+H_s+H_c$

$H_b=\int \omega_k a^\dagger a+0.5$

$H_s=\sum \omega_k b_k^\dagger b+0.5$

$H_c=\int \sum K(w,\omega)*(...)$
where $(...)$ is the sum of products of $a$, $a^{\dagger}$, $b$, $b^{\dagger}$

Comment: thanks!
oops I have a stray j just after the sum:
$H=...=\sum_j (...)$ <-- no j before the first (...)